# Preloading sprite kit textures

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, textures

So I was reading the apple documentation for best sprite kit practices. I came across this:

*For example, if your game uses the same textures for all its gameplay, you might create a special loading class that runs once at startup. You perform the work of loading the textures once, and then leave them in memory. If a scene object is deleted and recreated to restart gameplay, the textures do not need to be reloaded.*

And this would significantly help performance in my application.  Can someone point me in the right direction to how I would go about achieving this?

I presume I would call a function to load up texture's in my View Controller? And then access that texture atlas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, do you really want to cache the resources like that? Can't say I ever found a need for something of that nature. Anyways, if doing that somehow helps with your app's performance, then you can make a `TextureManager` class which would be a singleton (create separate file for `TextureManager` class), like this:

```
class TextureManager{

    private var textures = [String:SKTexture]()

    static let sharedInstance = TextureManager()

    private init(){}


    func getTexture(withName name:String)->SKTexture?{ return textures[name] }

    func addTexture(withName name:String, texture :SKTexture){


        if textures[name] == nil {
            textures[name] = texture
        }
    }

    func addTextures(texturesDictionary:[String:SKTexture]) {

        for (name, texture) in texturesDictionary {

            addTexture(withName: name, texture: texture)
        }
    }

    func removeTexture(withName name:String)->Bool {

        if textures[name] != nil {
            textures[name] = nil
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Here you are using dictionary and associate each texture with its name. Pretty simple concept. If there isn't a texture with the same name in a dictionary, then add it. Just beware of premature optimization.

The usage:

```
 //I used didMoveToView in this example, but more appropriate would be to use something before this method is called, like viewDidLoad, or doing this inside off app delegate.
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "game")

        let texture = atlas.textureNamed("someTexture1")

        let dictionary = [
             "someTexture2": atlas.textureNamed("someTexture2"),
             "someTexture3": atlas.textureNamed("someTexture3"),
             "someTexture4": atlas.textureNamed("someTexture4"),

        ]

        TextureManager.sharedInstance.addTexture(withName: "someTexture", texture: texture)
        TextureManager.sharedInstance.addTextures(dictionary)

    }
```

As I said, you have to put `TextureManager` implementation in a separate file, to make it real singleton. Otherwise, if you define it in `GameScene` for example, you will be able to call that private init, and then TextureManager will not be a real singleton.

So, with this code you can create some textures at the very beginning of the app lifecycle, like it is said in the docs:

> For example, if your game uses the same textures for all its gameplay,
>   you might create a special loading class that runs once at startup.

and fill the dictionary with them. Later on, whenever you need a texture, you will not use `atlas.textureNamed()` method, but rather load it from a dictionary property of a `TextureManager` class. Also, when transitioning between scenes, that dictionary will survive scene's deinits, and will persist while app is alive.